# Display view page with group results from controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my controller i am returning information based on the first letter of the name and then grouping all the names that start with that letter. All the names are already pre-ordered alphabetically - it is getting my view to reflect what i want to show.

Currently i have:

Amanda
Kim
Linda
Marly
Mike

This is how i am getting the names:

```
public IEnumerable<Names> GetNames(int? id, int? pageNumber)
    {
        int _pageNum = pageNumber.HasValue ? pageNumber.Value : 1;
        var userIndex = new NamesService().GetNames(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum).GroupBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1));
        var users = new List<NameUser>();
        foreach (var group in userIndex)
        {
            string curLetter = group.Key;
            foreach (NameUser user in group)
            {
                users.Add(user);
            }
        }
        return users.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

How can i get me view to display the letter before the group of names that belong to that letter - getting `curLetter` to print and then followed by `users.Add(user)`

so my results would be:

A
Amanda

K
Kim

L
Linda

M
Marly
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view assuming the model is

```
@model IEnumerable<NameUser>
```

then you could iterate through the collection and check to see if the first letter changed

```
@{
 string s = "-1";
}
@foreach( NameUser user in Model )
{
 if( user.Name.Substring(0, 1) != s )
 {
  s = user.Name.Substring(0, 1);
  <div>@s</div> 
 }
 <div>@user.Name</div>
}
```

The html may require an `@:` preface

Comment: I tried this but i got an error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` for `@foreach( NameUser user in Model )` Am i supposed to remove anything from my controller?

Comment: @Masriyah - What is the definition of the model for you page?

Comment: I added `@model IEnumerable<NameUser>` to the top of my view page under my using statements

Comment: NameUser is the Model i am using

Comment: @Masriyah - You should probably change the return type to match that in your action result. `IEnumerable<Names>` should be `IEnumerable<NameUser>` because that is what you are returning.

Comment: I made the changes but when i debug it says that `Model` is null